# Using the descriptions of the attributes given in the figure, convert the ERD shown in Figure P6.2 into a dependency diagram that is in at least 3NF

Tags: erd

I have no idea where to begin. Can you please help me?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start with learning third normal form

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form.

The key part of the third normal form is that every non-key attribute should rely on the key.

For example, fIrst name and last name should only be present in one table so as not to repeat this information for every row in which they attend a presentation. Keep separating attributes out until there is not data repeated in more than one place.

If you program, you might know the adage: DRY or Don't Repeat Yourself. This holds true for data as well as for programming as if you need to change one of the attendees names, you don't want to have to find and replace it in more than one place.